# Delete characters from a big file using vim or grep or other

Tags: vim, sed, grep, cut, tr

I have one big file which are contains around 500000 numbers, some of those numbers contains URl,Passwords , as you can see in my below example for my file , i would like to delete those numbers and keep only those numbers that contain Url,Password

```xml
101045
101046
101047
101048
101049            <Password>eee33ddrFDE</Password>
      <Url>http://www.example.com/9786140220447.php</Url>
--
      <Password>6tgHDDYUqLH</Password>
      <Url>http://www.example.com/9786140204102.php</Url>
101050
101051
101052
101053
101054
```

i have try to use cat and grep and vim with

```
:%s/^.\{6}//
```

but it will delete all numbers even those numbers which is have Url,Password  that i want to keep it.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of lines without password/URI info, you could try with:

`grep -E "[^0-9]+" filename`

Comment: thanks that's work with me & I'm sure the other answer as well will work due ,, i found there are two blank spaces after each number ..I've  deleted with vim using `:%s/\s\+$//` and run the commands

Answer (score 1):

You want to keep only those lines which contain password or url?.

You can use `sed`:

```
sed '/^[0-9]\+$/d'
```

or `grep`:

```
grep '[0-9]\+ '
```

Or in `vim`:

```
:g/^[0-9]\+$/d
```

Comment: for vim i got error 

     E486: Pattern not found: ^[0-9]\+$

and for sed & grep .. it will print all contains numbers & url,password.. like cat file

Comment: Can you be more clear about what exactly is your input and what exactly is your expected output? Please add that to the question

Answer (score 0):

This removes all line that are only number:

```
awk '!/^[0-9]*$/' file 
101049            <Password>eee33ddrFDE</Password>
      <Url>http://www.example.com/9786140220447.php</Url>
--
      <Password>6tgHDDYUqLH</Password>
      <Url>http://www.example.com/9786140204102.php</Url>
```

Or you can use this:

```
awk '/Password|http/' file
```

Prints only lines with  `Password` or `http`

---

Or you can clean it up some:

```
awk -F"[<>/]" '/Password/ {print "Password="$3} /http/ {print "Url="$5}' file
Password=eee33ddrFDE
Url=www.example.com
Password=6tgHDDYUqLH
Url=www.example.com
```

Comment: I've tried awk , is good but still he remove all numbers , what I'm looking for... i want to keep that numbers which contain the url,password ,,  like above ..101049 with url,password

Comment: @jassimmishal Then the first example should do.  It just print lines that is not single number.  So all of the line is intact.

Comment: after i run first example  it will print normal contain everything ID,URL,Password